# How to declare variables in a packer built AMI image

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, packer

I want to create a pre-install ami with packer to use in my ASG and came across a problem.
After creating an EFS, i want t be able to mount it in my AMI.
i am running below in provisioner:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport ${efs_dns_name}:/  /var/www/html
# Making Mount Permanent
sudo echo '${efs_dns_name}:/ /var/www/html nfs4 defaults,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

```
efs_dns_name = data.aws_efs_file_system.efs.dns_name
```

how can i declare my efs_dns_name variable in packer provisioner so it will populate in mount script?

Comment: Do you have a variables file with definitions? Also, please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: Yes we would need to see the `provisioner` block in the Packer `build` block.